# Textures messed up when building from the libgdx source code

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I need to edit the libgdx's source code to add a functionality that I need in my game ,but even before I modify the code I get some textures( like loaded with the wrong align or something) messed up when using the source code projects instead of the libgdx jars. Its not every texture and it seems to be random textures,the wrong textures look like that]

[image]

I am using the latest build from here  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx

What the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binaries are probably not in sync with the code. Run `ant -f fetch.xml` and copy the required .so files to your android project, replacing the old ones. If that doesn't help then download the natives jars and .so files (in the armeabi folders) from here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/ and manually replace the current ones with those. See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-Tests.

Comment: Updating the binaries and the gdx-natives.jar(after waiting 15 minutes for ant to build them!) in the desktop project fixed it.